# How to find the closest string match based on a user input in a pandas dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, difflib

My CSV dataset Scrips.csv is like:

```
Code,Id
500002,ABB
500003,AEGISLOG
500004,TPAEC
500005,AKARLAMIN
500006,ALPHADR
500008,AMARAJABAT
500009,AMBALALSA
500010,HDFC
500011,AMRTMIL-BDM
500012,ANDHRAPET
500013,ANSALAPI
```

I want to take user input in the form of a string and match it with "Id" column. I also want to see the closest matches if there is no exact match and ask the user to enter one of those matches. After the match, I want "Code" corresponding to the Id returned.

My desired output is:

```
Enter the Id: ABB
500002
```

I am not able to get anywhere with the below code:

```
import pandas as pd
from difflib import get_close_matches

df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\fc\BSE Scraper\Scrips.csv", index_col=0)

for row in df.index:
    if row == "ABB":
        print("True")
    elif len(get_close_matches(row, df.index())) > 0:
        print("Did you mean %s instead?" % get_close_matches(row, df.index())[0])
    else:
        print("No match found. Please try again.")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use custom function with convert `Id` column to `index` and `f-string`s:

```
def func(df, x):

    df = df.set_index('Id')
    m = df.index == x
    if m.sum() > 0:
        a = df.loc[x, 'Code']
        return  f'Exact match: {a}'
    else:
        val =  get_close_matches(x, df.index)
        if len(val) > 0:
            a = df.loc[val[0], 'Code']
            return f'Did you mean {val} instead for match {a}? '
        else:
            return "No match found. Please try again." 

print (func(df, 'ABB'))
Exact match: 500002
print (func(df, 'ABB1'))
Did you mean ABB instead for match 500002?
print (func(df, 'something'))
No match found. Please try again.
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the criteria for similar id you think is.

but I created some logic like this:

```py
def get_close_matches(string):
    global df
    get_sr2 = df['Id'][df['Id'].str.startswith(string[:2])]
    if len(get_sr2) !=0:
        return get_sr2.tolist()
    else:
        return ''

while True:
    get_id = input('Enter the Id : ')
    get_sr = df['Code'][df['Id'].isin([get_id])]
    if len(get_sr) != 0:
        print(get_sr.iloc[0])
        break
    elif get_close_matches(get_id):
        print("Do you mean one of the following?")
        print(get_close_matches(get_id),'\n')
        continue
    else:
        print("No match found. Please try again.")
        continue
```

```
Enter the Id : AB
Do you mean one of the following?
['ABB'] 

Enter the Id : ABB
500002
```

1. input string.
2. If there is an exact match, the code is returned. If there is an id starting with the input character, a list is returned.
3. If nothing was done in step 2, prints some texts.